# Innodb file per table is enabled from start but sudden change in ibdata1

Tags: centos, mysql

We have  a centos machine with innodb_file_per_table enabled at the very first. I have verified each table have .frm and .ibd. What happened was I added some new indexes and suddenly I see my ibdata1 is now sized at 26Mb and its keep being updated but no change in size. Is there anything to worry but whyis my ibdata1 suddenly being active ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with innodb_file_per_table, the main system ibdata files are still used.  if not growing, but constantly being accessed, it could just be temp tables generate by queries.  remember, the system ibdata files never shrink, and innodb reuses this "space".

Comment: I dont have temp tables in my system. I grow from 10Mb to 28Mb but stay constant on 28Mb for now. But I can see there is updates going on in it. What is it going in that ?

Comment: paste a "show full processlist" when you experience this condition...

Comment: It shows mostly are sleep with one is bin log for the replication. The sleep is mainly due to I am using pooling.